# 'IHtmlHelper<dynamic>' does not contain a definition for 'Widget' in nopcommerce 4.0

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nopcommerce-4.0

I am getting the red line and shows the title error when I add

**@Html.Widget("home_page_top")** and

**@Html.Action("TopicBlock", "Topic", new { systemName = "HomePageText" })**

in nop.web Home view in nopcommerce. 
And the full error shows the following message i.e. :

**Error CS1061  'IHtmlHelper' does not contain a definition for 'Widget' and no accessible extension method 'Widget' accepting a first argument of type 'IHtmlHelper' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)**

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution. I am going in a wrong way I am doing code 3.8 in 4.0. Thats why I am getting this issue.

Comment: what is the solution? how did you modify the code to work?

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else comes across this question, in version 4.0 the code for adding a widget zone has changed. Use this :

@await Component.InvokeAsync("Widget", new { widgetZone = "custom_widget_zone" })